# How do I POST a file from S3 as FormData to another API?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, axios, multipartform-data

I've got a node.js Lambda function that downloads a `.docx` file from an S3 bucket.

```
const object = await s3.getObject({
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: templateName,
}).promise();

return object.Body;
```

I then want to take this file and, using axios, post it up to another API to convert it to a PDF (a [Gotenberg](https://thecodingmachine.github.io/gotenberg/) instance).

However, I keep getting two blank pages back as the conversion result, which suggests it's sent *some* data as it's a two page Word document.

I'm currently using the `object.Body` value (which, when logged, is a buffer: `<Buffer 50 4b 03 04 14 [...]`).

Then, I'm trying to put it into a POST request to Gotenberg:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('files', object.Body, { filename: 'suitability-purchase.docx' });

const response = await axios.post(`${documentConversionService}/convert/office`, formData, {
    headers: {
        ...formData.getHeaders()
    }
});

console.log('Conversion finished', response);
return response.data;
```

Which returns a PDF document with two blank pages.

My question is, how do I correctly post the [FormData](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) for in-memory file data? Am I just missing something obvious?

I've downloaded the document from S3 manually and sent it to the Gotenberg API using Postman and it works fine. I don't think there's anything wrong with the source document; it *appears* to be how I'm sending the document in code.

I've tried a few variations of the different ways of making an axios call with form data but can't get it to not generate blank pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad question on my part.

The problem was axios needs to be told to return the data as a stream. And then converting the result to a buffer fixes the issue:

```
const stb = require('@jorgeferrero/stream-to-buffer');

const response = await axios({
    url: `${documentConversionService}/convert/office`,
    method: 'post',
    headers: formData.getHeaders(),
    data: formData,
    responseType: 'stream',
});

return await stb.streamToBuffer(response.data);
```